# anchor tag is not working in php and html is rendered from other file

Tags: php, html

I am trying get data from a database and pasting it on a webpage in table form and in each table data there are names which have other details in database which I also have to show on other webpage if that name is clicked. I got stuck when anchor tag is not working.

NOT WORKING means that name in anchor tag is like normal text not link, though text turns blue with underline but its not acquiring its linking property.

[image]

Table in which I am getting data from database is working **plus** I am also trying to give anchor tag to table data which are simple names which would link to another file.

I am using 2 file one is .php and other is .html of **same name**.

Here are some of the LOC I am using and related to this. I have omitted other 3 columns.

**file.php**

```
<?php
...

$query="select name from table1 order by name";

$rs=mysql_query($query);

$table = '<table>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  $cname = $row["name"];

  $table .= '<tr>
             <td><a href="file3.php">'.$cname.'</a></td> /*<a></a> not working*/
             </tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
include_once 'file.html';
?>
```

**file.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<form>..</form> /*passes user input to PHP file1*/

<p><?php echo $table;?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Html is rendered from html file.

**file3.php** is the page which I am trying to link through names.

I am using XAMPP 1.7.7 and PHP 5.3.8

Any useful suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you could provide the HTML received by the browser as well. You can usually fetch this through some kind of "View Source" option within the browser. This will let everyone see what the result returned to the browser looks like.

Comment: Is HTML setup to be parsed as PHP in the Apache configuration? Also, what is the resulting output as seen by your browser?

Comment: Please re-open this question. I have edited this and clearly stating what I need.

Comment: Why we still writing deprecated code. Move to mysqli, pdo or any good framework like Eloquent. Please stop using Mysql functions!!! It hurts my eyes!

Comment: It was an old question. Now, it is hurting my eyes too. Vote to delete this question, please.

Answer (score 8):

Look at your query, you are using `cname` as an index for `$row` and your query fetches `name`

```
$query="select name from table1 order by name";
              --^--

$cname = $row["cname"];
               --^--
```

Is your error reporting turned off? You should get an error for this.. **FOR SURE**

> Note: You should stop using mysql_() as it will be deprecated soon,
>   start using [mysqli_()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead...

Comment: @Kits why you are concatenating the strings??? just echo them out, and don't echo so much of html...just open close php brackets accordingly

Comment: @Kits and also you cannot use echo statement in an html file :p

Comment: Concatenation is needed. I have to that is table form. If you have any other code then please enlight me

Comment: @Mr.Alien you are not getting it right. Please try to understand that my code is fine, the only thing is that a tag is not getting is property of linking.

Comment: @Kits Ok I got it, you are throwing out html in another file.what's the source of the rendered html?

Comment: html is rendered from file 2

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use 'mysql_fetch_assoc' to 'mysql_fetch_array.
2. Check if the table has values.
3. change '$row["cname"]' to '$row["name"]'

Answer (score -3):

This is your code

```
$table .= '<tr>
           <td><a href="file3.php">'.$cname.'</a></td> /*<a></a> not working*/
           </tr>';
```

Just replace the single quote by double quotes

You just need to replace this code with following code:
$table = "";

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  $cname = $row["name"];

  $table .= "<tr>
             <td><a href='file3.php'>$cname</a></td> 
             </tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
```

This code will print actual variable $cname value  from your database 
Please try this.

Comment: this will echo out the variable name, he is using single quote `'`, you need double quotes `"` so -1

Comment: youre just printing $cname on html, not the actual variable. -1